# html Input form wont submit?

Tags: html, forms

So simply trying to make a html form submit but my layout uses a lot of divs and classes and doesn't seem to be getting the names / ids of them to post i think its not working due to everything inside the form the div's etc but of course this is the layout its late in the morning so could be missing something/ missed something out

```
            <?php


            if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"])) {

                echo "testing";
            }

            ?>

                    <h3 class="widget-title text-dark">
                                    Cart summary


                                </h3>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>







                <div class="widget-body">


                        <div class="row">

                        <form action="checkout.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 margin-b-30">

                                <div class="row">


                                    <div class="col-sm-6">

                                            <label>First Name*</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="John"> </div>
                                        <!--/form-group-->

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Last Name*</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname"  placeholder="Doe"> </div>
                                        <!--/form-group-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Full Address*</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="124, Lorem Street.."> </div>
                                        <!--/form-group-->
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Post code*</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Post code" placeholder="G52 2LW"> </div>
                                        <!--/form-group-->
                                    </div>




                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>phone*</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="123-345-3322"> </div>
                                        <!--/form-group-->
                                    </div>
                                <div class="payment-option">
                                    <ul class=" list-unstyled">
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-radio  m-b-20">
                                                <input id="radioStacked1" name="radio-stacked" type="radio" class="custom-control-input"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Payment on delivery</span>
                                                <br> <span>Please send your cheque to Store Name, Store Street, Store Town, Store State / County, Store Postcode.</span> </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="custom-control custom-radio  m-b-10">
                                                <input name="radio-stacked" name="submit2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input"> <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Paypal <img src="images/paypal.jpg" alt="" width="90"></span> </label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <p class="text-xs-center"> <a href="?id=<?php echo $id1 ; ?>" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">Pay now</a> </p>






                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </form>
```

A big thank you in advance

http://prntscr.com/g7gc12

Comment: Where do the div's close...

Comment: ive made a edit all divs close inside the form area

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g7gc12

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it it was the button i changed this

```
  <p class="text-xs-center"> <a href="" id="submit" name="submit"  type="button">Pay now</a> </p>
```

to

```
   <div class="col-xs-12">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-lg theme-btn" type="submit">Update Info</button>
                                                </div>
```

Problem fixed thank you